# Recovering Hard Disk

Tags: hard-drive, external-hard-drive, data-recovery

Is there a way to recover data from a hard drive when it's not detected anymore by the PC?

I've looked around and all the solutions seem to assume that the hard drive is still detectable.

How can I do this?

Comment: Maybe this will help:
[http://superuser.com/questions/1078/harddrive-in-the-freezer-ever-work-for-you](http://superuser.com/questions/1078/harddrive-in-the-freezer-ever-work-for-you)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sometimes deepfreezing it will allow bits to move back into place for long enough to get data off.

Comment: Thought you were pulling our leg there for a second. Then I googled it. Weird.

Comment: Yeah, sounds like a load of rubbish, but apparently it can help

Comment: Freezing does work, but I think it has more to do with the spindle shrinking just a bit more than the platter, allowing the platter to move more freely, and less to do with "bits moving back into place"

Comment: I've had good luck with this.   Remember to act fast.. You are racing against the drive heating up.  Don't try to grab the whole drive in one shot.  Do a folder at a time.  Then if the driver stops working freeze again and start where you left off.

Answer (score 2):

A quick google search provides the follow:

[How to Recover Data From a Dead Hard Drive](http://www.popularmechanics.com/technology/how_to/4294038.html)

[Recover a Dead Hard Disk](http://www.wikihow.com/Recover-a-Dead-Hard-Disk)

[How to Recover Dead Hard Drive Data](http://hacknmod.com/hack/how-to-recover-dead-hard-drive-data/)

It's also possible to find software that will take a dead 'as in non-detecable' harddrive and do a slow deep level scan of the drive and recover data from it.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

If it doesn't spin up, it's time for the professionals. They will need a clean room to open it up.